# Go to directory in link (instead of opening the file)

Tags: key-bindings

I have a text file with lots of links to local directories which cointains .pdf files.

I know about `gf`, but is there a way to open only the directory and not the file?

For example, from this link `~/myDir/subfolder/file.pdf` jump to `/subfolder`

or even better open the .pdf in a pdf reader from vim

Thanks in advance for your insights and experience

Comment: If you don't have much use of `gF`, remap it to do `:browse` based on the cursor position? Better, map it to `:Explore` (see `:help netrw`)

Comment: For reading text in a PDF file, the [afterimage plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-afterimage) may suffice.

Comment: Do you have found a solution to your problem? Could you share it with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to configure the `gx` command to open the pdf file.

The netrw plugin has to be active and you may have to adapt the following .vimrc code to your platform.

```
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer = "-"
function! NFH_pdf(filename)
  " Add the call to open a:filename on your platform
endfunction
```

Comment: This is super useful

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)